# How to draw 2 LineCharts with xAxis with Strings

Tags: ios, charts, swift3, ios-charts

I am new in programming and swift and I am trying to make a chart with 2 lines. And on top of the chart to enumerate the Array of Strings that I have (DD-MM in my case). I managed to draw just one line like so:

```
 let testArrayTemp = [22.43, 14.86,20.63, 17.08,23.68,14.12,11.09,13.89, 15.0, 9.86, 7.71,10.0,11.94, 8.68, 8.91,6.81, 9.03,8.89, 9.7, 9.26, 9.43,10.22, 9.04,8.04, 7.56,10.44, 7.22, 13.67,9.44, 7.67, 5.99]
     let testArrayFeel = [20.43, 13.86,10.63, 15.08,22.68,11.12,10.09,15.89, 13.0, 6.86, 5.71,11.0,10.94, 7.68, 6.91,5.81, 3.03,5.89, 7.7, 8.26, 8.43, 11.22, 6.04,7.04, 6.56,11.44, 6.22, 12.67,10.44, 5.67, 4.99]
    let testDayArray = ["Oct 2, 2016", "Oct 3, 2016", "Oct 4, 2016", "Oct 5, 2016", "Oct 6, 2016", "Oct 7, 2016", "Oct 8, 2016", "Oct 9, 2016", "Oct 10, 2016", "Oct 11, 2016", "Oct 12, 2016", "Oct 13, 2016", "Oct 14, 2016", "Oct 15, 2016", "Oct 16, 2016", "Oct 17, 2016", "Oct 18, 2016", "Oct 19, 2016", "Oct 20, 2016", "Oct 21, 2016", "Oct 22, 2016", "Oct 23, 2016", "Oct 24, 2016", "Oct 25, 2016", "Oct 26, 2016", "Oct 27, 2016", "Oct 28, 2016", "Oct 29, 2016", "Oct 30, 2016", "Oct 31, 2016", "Nov 1, 2016"]
    setChart(dataPoints: testDayArray, valuesTempChart: testArrayTemp, valuesFeelChart: testArrayFeel)
}

//MARK:- Set Chart
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], valuesTempChart: [Double], valuesFeelChart: [Double])
{
    var tempEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count
    {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: valuesTempChart[i])
        tempEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let lineChartDataSetTemp = LineChartDataSet(values: tempEntries, label: "Temperature")
    lineChartDataSetTemp.setColor(UIColor.red)
   // lineChartDataSetTemp.mode = .cubicBezier
    lineChartDataSetTemp.drawCirclesEnabled = true
    lineChartDataSetTemp.lineWidth = 2.0
    lineChartDataSetTemp.circleRadius = 5.0
    lineChartDataSetTemp.highlightColor = UIColor.green
    lineChartDataSetTemp.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true

    var dataSets = [IChartDataSet]()
    dataSets.append(lineChartDataSetTemp)
    let lineChartDataTemp = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
    lineChart.data = lineChartDataTemp
    lineChart.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)

    lineChart.noDataText = "There is no provided data from the server. Please check out later!"
}
```

but it looks like so: [image: Graph]

what I need to do to show the String array on top (with the days) and to add one more line. please any idea, or maybe a link to a tutorial in SWIFT 3 not other version, cause they made a lot of changes, and nothing from swift 2 tutorials works as it should, but the autocorrection does even worse. 
I would like it to look something like this: (but with 2 lines and days in stead of months)

[image]

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is repeat the process for the feels data. Reference the code below.

```
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], valuesTempChart: [Double],valuesFeelChart: [Double])
{
var tempEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
var feelEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

for i in 0..<dataPoints.count
{
    let dataEntryOne = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: valuesTempChart[i])
    let dataEntryTwo = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: valuesFeelChart[i])
    tempEntries.append(dataEntryOne)
    feelEntries.append(dataEntryTwo)
}

let lineChartDataSetTemp = LineChartDataSet(values: tempEntries, label: "Temperature")
let lineChartDataSetFeels = LineChartDataSet(values: feelEntries, label: "Feels")

var dataSets = [IChartDataSet]()
dataSets.append(lineChartDataSetTemp)
dataSets.append(lineChartDataSetFeels)
let lineChartD = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
lineChart.data = lineChartD
lineChart.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)

lineChart.noDataText = "There is no provided data from the server. Please check out later!"
```

}

Hope this helps!